# How can I detect ignored/rejected posted QEvent to QStateMachine

Tags: qt, qstatemachine

I need to see if a custom posted event to the state machine was accepted or not. My approach is to subclass QStateMachine.  See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/statemachine-api.html section **Events, Transitions and Guards**

I'm wondering is there is not something I missed in the code below. Is there not another/better approach?

Basically here is the same as per the Qt Doc:

```
bool MyStateTransition::eventTest(QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() != QEvent::Type(QEvent::User+1)) // MyEvent
        return false;

    MyEvent *se = static_cast<MyEvent*>(e);

    if(m_value != se->value)
    {
        se->setRejected(true);
        return false;
    }
    qDebug() << "MyStateTransition::eventTest() - Transition " << m_value << " accepting event " << se->value;
    se->setRejected(false);
    return true;
}
```

And the simplest way I could find to far to detect the reject is this:

```
void MyStateMachine::endSelectTransitions(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() != QEvent::Type(QEvent::User+1)) return;

    MyEvent *se = static_cast<MyEvent*>(event);
    if(se->rejected())
        emit eventRejected(se);
    else 
        //Not really needed since we can use triggered() which will fire after
        emit eventAccepted(se); 

}
```

Comment: What is this `MyStateMachine::endSelectTransitions` method?

Comment: A virtual method that gets called when the state machine has "passed over" all the target transitions, (part of QStateMachine)

Comment: I don't see it in docs. Can you post some link to it?

Comment: Yup, you are right! Not in the doc.  But a quick google gave this: http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QStateMachine.html#PySide.QtCore.QStateMachine.endSelectTransitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally answering my own question: It works but is basically a **hack** since not officially documented.